# Saving the return value from an API call to an existing Database

Tags: php, sql, parsing, curl, response

I have a form that we submit after entering the details.
Upon submit, it sends the data to a PHP file, that has the API calls for my service provider.

First,  I save all the details in a local database, along with the name of the Agent and Timestamp, passed from the previous form.
After saving the data, I then send all relevent data to the service provide using their API. I use curl to post the data.

If all goes well, I get the following response

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.8.0 Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 16:38:16 GMT Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST {"success":true,"message":"1 row successfully inserted","warnings":[],"data":{"TRANSACTIONID":"SS_100526","STATUS":"Accepted, Verifying Funds"}}
```

Now, instead of this long winded message, I want to display just a single line - "

> Data submitted successfully. Transaction ID for this sale is:
>   SS_100526

" on the same page instead of a new blank window.
Also, I want to save the returned transaction ID in the same local table where I save the sale details before calling the API.

I have tried to use various JSON options and also to use it as a string to parse, but can't seem to get it to work.
Any idea how can I properly display the return response and also save the returned transaction id in my existing database?

Here is the PHP code that I am currently using with comments

```html
<?php
 ob_start();
 session_start();
 require_once '../dbconnect.php';// to connect to the database on my server 
 
 if( !isset($_SESSION['user']) ) {
  header("Location: ../index.php"); //fetching session details 
  exit;
 }
 // select loggedin users detail
 $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
 $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
 $userid=$userRow['userEmail'];
 $usernam=$userRow['userName'];
 $timestamp = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');

$apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Your API Key
$apiEndPoint = 'https://portalDev.example.com';  // URL for API
 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demodata");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//collecting the user details to save in the database
 $source = 'client1';
    $last_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['last_name']);//'Doe',
    $first_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['first_name']);//'John',
    $address= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['address']);//'123 Broadway',
    $city= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['city']);//'New York',
    $state= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['state']);//'NY',
    $zip= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['zip']);//'10016',
    $amount= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['amount']);//'5.99',
    $testmode = 0; // In test mode, you must use 1.
 $agentName = $usernam;
 $userMail = $userid;
 $saletimestamp = $timestamp;
 
 
 
// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (source, last_name, first_name, address, city, state, zip, amount, testmode, agentName, userMail, saletimestamp) VALUES ('$source', '$last_name', '$first_name', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip','$amount', '$testmode', '$agentName','$userMail','$saletimestamp')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  echo "Records added successfully.";
 //header('Location: http://localhost/login/bsdev/success.html');
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
 
 //collate data for sending to the service provider in the format they have shared with us.
$postFields = array(
    'SOURCE'=> 'client1',
    'LASTNAME'=> urlencode($_POST['last_name']),//'Doe',
    'FIRSTNAME'=> urlencode($_POST['first_name']),//'John',
    'ADDRESS'=> urlencode($_POST['address']),//'123 Broadway',
    'CITY'=> urlencode($_POST['city']),//'New York',
    'STATE'=> urlencode($_POST['state']),//'NY',
    'ZIPCODE'=> urlencode($_POST['zip']),//'10016',
    'AMOUNT'=> urlencode($_POST['amount']),//'5.99',
    'TESTMODE' => 1 // In test mode, you must use 1.
);
 
 
$process = curl_init($apiEndPoint . "/api/v1/transaction");
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apikey . ":" . $apikey); // Basic Authentication using your API key
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 
 
 
$response = (string)curl_exec($process);

echo $response;

//This is the response we get after curl_exec:
//Records added successfully.HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.8.0 Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 13:58:57 GMT Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST {"success":true,"message":"1 row successfully inserted","warnings":[],"data":{"TRANSACTIONID":"SS_100526","STATUS":"Accepted, Verifying Funds"}}

curl_close($process);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, may i suggest you to use a framework instead of vanilla php, as this code is not really safe to use in a production environment.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (source, last_name, first_name, address, city, state, zip, amount, testmode, agentName, userMail, saletimestamp) VALUES ('$source', '$last_name', '$first_name', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip','$amount', '$testmode', '$agentName','$userMail','$saletimestamp')";
```

When you write a query like this, it is not safe from SQL Injection. Malicious users can compromise the security of your webapp like this. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to write your queries.

Now back to your question. I expect that once you make a request to the API, you already know the Transaction ID.

When using cURL for making HTTP requests, you can use [curl_getinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) to get the information you want from a response.

`curl_getinfo($process, $options)`

`$options` is here an optional array you may pass. Use [curl_setopt_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php) to put all your cURL settings in one array instead. That way you only have to use one function instead of using `curl_setopt()` seven times.

Retrieve the status code from the response from `curl_getinfo`, then write an `if` statement like so.

```
if($statusCode === 200) {
   echo 'Data submitted successfully. Transaction ID for this sale is: ' . $id;
} else {
   echo 'Something went wrong.';
}
```

Once you run `curl_exec()`, you need to close a cURL session to free the resources. Use `curl_close($process)`. Make sure `$response` is an array like so `$response[]`. Remove the `(string)` before `curl_exec`.

After that, use `json_decode($response)` to translate the JSON string to a PHP array, which you can use to retrieve the needed data.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Nico. Your suggestion about SQL injections is extremely valuable. It's my first PHP code so all help is appreciated :)

I am, however still stuck with this bit.
The transaction id is not known to me at the time of making the API call. Once I send the call with all fields, it responds with a return code. If the call is successful, then it sends a transaction ID, else it gives an error. What kind of array can I pass to get the return info such that it can be parsed in different bits, like Status, Transaction ID, Error code, etc.